# Can not access a specific LAN IP on http/https, from a specific IP in my LAN

Tags: networking, ip

I'm having a very weird problem. Let me outlign:

I have a pfSense box with IP `192.168.1.1`.
It allows connections from anywhere inside LAN, on any port and any protocol, which is confirmed by me being able to access it from any IP, besides one of them: `192.168.1.7`.

The machine on the IP that can't access the box, is running Mac OS X Yosemite. I have tried Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera. Still can't access it on http/https. I can SSH into the box and I can ping it.

- I cleared out some things saved in the Mac keychain pertaining to the `1.1` IP (used to be a different machine on that IP), but no change ensued.
- There are no Firewall rules preventing the `1.7` IP to access the box.
- I `tail -f`'d the syslog whilst trying to reach the IP through http but nothing odd pops up. Not sure if there's a different log I could try though?

I've come as far as understood that it has to do with Mac OS X, but I have no idea what it might be.

So I suppose my question is this:
What could potentially cause this? Again, it's only http/https traffic that doesn't seem to go through.

Edit: I ran tcpdump while requesting the IP on http:

https://pastebin.com/hUHisGbt

I'm not familiar with tcpdump, but does this mean there are requests being sent to edgekey.net!? And why would that be!?

I also tried restarting the WebUI and PHP-FPM. No change.

Edit: I found the answer to this issue.

The MTU was set to 9000 on the pfsense box and my iMac 27" can apparently not handle that. Setting it to default allowed me to access the box again.

Comment: Can you use something like tcpdump to see if http/https traffic is hitting/leaving the box? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Just a guess, but this happens to me every couple of months on one of my pfsense boxes, and it only happens to my Ubuntu workstations. I usually just have to ssh into it and restart the web (option 11) and php service (option 16) and everything's good for another couple months. What pfsense version is this?

Comment: @davidgo Did a tcpdump. Not sure what to make of it. I've amended my question.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Tried that, didn't work :-/

Comment: We really need more complete tcpdump info to help.  The snippet you provided seems to show a DNS lookup of some sort - it does not show the traffic between your systems.

Comment: @davidgo I've put a full tcpdump (i.e. from initial get of the host to its timeout) into the pastebin linked. I have no idea what to make of it tbh.

Comment: Lines 211-215 show that the request was being received and responded to by 192.168.1.7 - therefor the problem is not at the routing/firewall level on the pfsense box.   What exactly is returned by 192.168.1.1 when a request is made from 192.168.1.7?  I postulate that something is being displayed/said - just not what you are expecting.

Comment: @davidgo That looks to be right before it times out. I have no idea how to figure out what is actually being said though :-/

Comment: What do you mean by "times out" - what is being displayed in the web page window, and what OS is running on 192.168.1.7?

Comment: @davidgo After 30s the attempt to get 192.168.1.1 times out. I.e. it stops trying. 1.7 is running Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: @davidgo Holy crap I found the error... I set the MTU on the pfsense box to 9000 w/out even considering the Mac might not be able to handle that. I now removed that setting and it frickin worked!

Comment: Well done. You should post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial-and-error, I found the error: It was the MTU on the pfSense box that was too high for the device. It was set to 9000 (jumbo frames).

Reverting it to default (1500) solved the issue.